# Truffle (no module named truffle)

Tags: npm, truffle, consensys-truffle

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\something\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\runpy.py", line 196, in _run_module_as_main
return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
File "C:\Users\something\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\runpy.py", line 86, in *run_code
exec(code, run_globals)
File "C:\Users\something\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Scripts\truffle.exe_*main**.py", line 4, in 
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'truffle'

I have installed truffle but this is the error that I get when I run any truffle command

Comment: Please provide some more information. Ex - Which node version are you using?